# PID not shown under Services in the Task Manager on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, port, task-manager, pid

I'm trying to run a program that defaults to port 9000 but there is an unknown source using that port. I found the PID by using,

```
    netstat -aon | more
```

and went to the task managers service tab where I can see all the other PID's that were listed with the above command but the PID corresponding to port 9000 is not listed. What is going on here and what can I do to terminate whoever is using this port?

I am using Windows 8.1 and I followed this tutorial to do the steps I mentioned,
http://mywindows8.org/check-which-tcpip-ports-are-in-use/#comment-519600

Answer (score 0):

`netstat` has a habit of not showing all program owners. Try [TCPView](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/TCPView.zip) instead. This is especially true if "System" is the owner of the thread the port is being used on which is possible since some services do run under the "System" process.

Comment: wait...the PID of the process was 9000? Was the port *and* the PID 9000? I'm confused.

Comment: Opps no my mistake I used a bad example for the PID I think it was like 8390 or something.